# How to save a variable in grails app for the lifecycle of the application

Tags: grails

In one of my controllers I'm creating a long list by iterating over a lot of elements (not DB related) before the form is shown. Every time this form this shown I have this piece of code running and doing the same thing.

Is it possible to save this list into a variable so that I don't iterate over the elements each time? If so, how do I access it in my controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `servletContext` has global scope and supports Map access like `session` and `request`, so you can store it like this:

```
def someList = ...
servletContext.foo = someList
```

and later retrieve it:

```
def someList = servletContext.foo
```